# Get a list of fields from a class that is instantiated within a list, and compare them

Tags: c#, frameworks, game-engine

I have a `IReadOnlyList` of instantiated classes. I would like to get all the `public` `static` fields that exists within each of these classes, and compare their names (the actual variable/field name as strings) to another group of strings (our case from an enumerator value name).

```
internal static string AttachBindablesToConfig(IReadOnlyList<Drawable> children)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < children.Count; i++)
    {
        var type = children[i].GetType(); // Get the class type
        var props = type.GetFields(); // Get fields within class
        return (props[0].GetValue(null)).ToString(); // Return a specific, testing purposes 
    }
    return "Failed";
}

// in another class

    Children = new Drawable[] { new Class1(), new Class2() };
    ..AttachBindablesToConfig(Children); // get value and display to screen

public class Class1
{
    // find these fields, and return their names (x, y, z) in a string format.
    public static someClass x;
    public static anotherClass y;
    public static int z;
}
```

This approach does not seem to be working. I would like an explanation as to why it doesn't work, and a clear answer which can hopefully fix this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I would like to get all the `public` `static` fields that exists within
>   each of these classes

I'm guessing you need to include the appropriate *Binding Flags*

[BindingFlags Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.bindingflags(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Specifies flags that control binding and the way in which the search
>   for members and types is conducted by reflection.

```
var fieldNames = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static)
                               .Select(x => x.Name)
                               .ToList();
```

**Note** : I'm confused as to whether you want the name or the value, the above gets the list of names

If you want the value as well you could Select like this

```
.Select(x => x.Name + " = " + x.GetValue(children[i]))
```

Comment: I apologize for not wording my description accurately. I want the name of the variable, not its value. `public static int x = 3; // I want x, not 3`

Comment: @Frontear i haven't tested this , however it should work, fingers crossed